# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - when parsing a csv file

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I want to transform a csv file. My file looks like that:

[image]

I am using the `opencsv` libary to parse my csv. That is my `run` method to parse the file:

```
public void run() throws Exception {


        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), ';');
        String [] nextLine;
        int i = -1;
        String fileName = "";
        String companyName = "";
        String currency = "";
        String writerPath;
        List<String> returnList = null;
        List<String> dateList = null;

        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null && i < 10) {
            String[] line = nextLine;
            System.out.println(line[0]);
            System.out.println(line);
            i++;

            //fileName of the String 
            if(!line[0].contains("NULL")) {
                fileName = line[0];
            }

            writerPath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\CSVOutput\\" + fileName + ".csv";
            //write csv file
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(writerPath), ';');

            //write Header
            String[] entries = "Name;Date;TotalReturn;Currency".split(";");
            writer.writeNext(entries);

            //create Content

            //companyName of the String 
            if(!line[1].contains("Name")) {
                companyName = line[1];
                System.out.println(companyName);
            }

            //currency 
            if(!line[2].contains("CURRENCY")) {
                currency = line[2];
            }


            //total returns
            returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(line[0].contains("NULL")) {
                for(int j = 3; j <= line.length; j++) {
                    returnList.add(line[j]); // EXCPETION COMES HERE!
                }
            }

            //"Name;Date;TotalReturn;Currency"
            List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            for(int m = 0; m <= line.length; m++) {
                data.add(new String[] {companyName, "lolo", "hereComesTheDateLater", currency});
            }

            writer.writeAll(data);

            //close Writer
            writer.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");


    }

}
```

I am getting an

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3039
    at com.TransformCSV.main.ParseCSV.run(ParseCSV.java:78)
    at com.TransformCSV.main.ParseCSV.main(ParseCSV.java:20)
```

at this line: `returnList.add(line[j]);`?

Why? What are possible ways to fix that?

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: You should use the debugger to help you debug this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `j < line.length` and **not** `<=`. If there are `10` elements in an Array then there is not an item at index `10` - you only have `0-9`.

Further using loads of variables and assigning them is not the preferred way to parse CSV. Java is an Object Orientated language.

Use an `Object` to represent each line and bind the line using the [opencsv javabean API](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#javabean-integration)

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing the file till length of file `<=` instead you have to use `<`. It will access the file till `line.length - 1`

Replace with this

```
for(int j = 3; j <line.length; j++) {
     returnList.add(line[j]); 
}
```